# How do I align all the vertices to be straight vertically?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, vertices, edges

[image]

Hi, I want all the vertices to be lined up straight for my mesh, for some reason I am unable to do so... any help appreciated.

Comment: Assuming what is shown is your *actual mesh* and you don't need a general solution... select the horizontal edges and dissolve them, then re-add seams. Wont exactly work if your top and bottom aren't exactly lined up, but if that's the case, it's unclear what result you would want, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Set the *Transform Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins* and select only the **vertical** edges, not the horizontal circles.

[image: select vertical edges]

2. Scale the edges on X and Y (i.e. not Z) down to 0 by hitting <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image: scale to 0]

Now they might not be centered along with the top and bottom circles, but you can adjust that with moving on X/Y with <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and maybe snapping.

Comment: I noticed that this method will fail when the inner is not a circle, after that it will no longer be a cylinder.

Comment: @XY As long as Atharva doesn't provide more information if the straightening is needed for other shapes as well, it works. And even when it's not a circle, making it a circle if needed is not so complicated afterwards.

Comment: My model is basically a cup, so it is like a cylinder inwards with all the edges in this formation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the *Mesh: EdgeFlow* addon, select these edge loops and right click > *Set Flow*, tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*:

[image]